# Trying to convert Blob to excel file. Excel cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, angular, excel, typescript

My frontend code in angular typescript below:-

```
public async downloadReport(exportCall: Observable<any>, fileName: string, fixedFileName = false): Promise<void> {

        const result = await firstValueFrom(exportCall);

        const responseBody = result.body ? result.body : result;
    
        let type: string;
        type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
    
        this.downloadFile(new Blob([responseBody], { type }), fileName, fileType, fixedFileName);
}    

public downloadFile(file: Blob, fileName: string, fileType: ExportFileType, fixedFileName = false): void {

        const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = data;
        link.download = fixedFileName ? fileName : this.getFileName(fileName, fileType);
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        link.remove();
}
```

My backend endpoint:-

```
    [Route("export")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExportReport(Request request)
    {
        return await GetHttpResponseWithIActionResultAndResponseBaseAsync(async () =>
        {
            var response = await service.Export(request);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(response.Content.Document);
            var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            var filestream = new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = response.Content.FileName
            };

            return filestream;
        });
    }
```

Similar code is working fine in other areas of the application for downloading excel however here when I try to open the downloaded excel I see an error message saying: `Excel cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does, for instance, the blob have the same content-length as the response body? What about the file that is downloaded? Same length or truncated?

Comment: @spender Blob size is 869977 and the downloaded excel file is 850kb